# WPF Text Changed Event Not Firing on 'S'

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application that is a user control hosted in another company's application.

The textboxes I have created will accept all characters and numbers except for capital 'S'.  They are MVVM bound to string properties that work on any other character than 'S'. The text changed events fire for every other character as well.  The on key down and up will fire off for the "S" character though.  The text box does not display the character.

I read somewhere that sometimes a conflict happens with hosted user controls in which it will not accept certain inputs, but I am unable to set the ElementHost property needed to address this as I do not have programmatic access to the host window in this case.  The control is hosted by another User Control which is hosted under the third party application I am adding an application too.

I am dumbfounded as every other key works.  I checked this on another machine to find the same problem, so it is not hardware dependent.

Comment: What about asking the third party if they're intercepting the `S` keystroke for another command or function?

Comment: When you say your ViewModel works on any other character than 'S' what does that mean?  Can you post the ViewModel for us and any other converters / code behind you might be using with this?

Comment: It is a basic view model pattern with a RaisedPropertyChanged event and a string property. It is the same pattern I have used hundreds of times, and is not the cause of the problem.  I do not use converters, only the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: As to the 3rd party...I cannot count on their support.  License for the software is 35k a year per user, you would think we would have excellent support for their SDK/API but nope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you've subscribed for the **TextChanged** event. If that is the case just subscribe for **PreviewKeyDown**, apply your filter and set e.Handled to true to sink it.

```
private void PreviewKeyDownFilter(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.S && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift))
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: I thought this might work since I had not tried handling it on the Preview, but alas it did not. See below for the only fix I found.

Comment: Gave credit because the Preview thing helped me find a work around.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a not so clean way to handle it.  I am not happy with the solution as I would like to understand the root cause, but this works functionally.

```
 private void IOTextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.S && (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightShift)))
        {
            TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
            tb.Text = tb.Text + "S";
            tb.CaretIndex = tb.Text.Length;
            e.Handled = true;
        }

    }
```

If anyone else has any better idea...

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a separate WPF app that does the same: dummy app that hosts a dummy control that hosts your control. If everything works OK, there is a 99% chance their app has some accelerator shortcut or another kind of logic that eats that "S" char.